TikZ: Shapes with an angular colour gradient
Cross-posting from Stack Overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/78347764/2777074
Good people! I'm trying to draw some shapes with an angular colour gradient, but I am unable to find the general syntax for how fill a shape like that. I'm going to need to draw an awful lot of these diagrams, but to give you an idea of the basic way I want these things to look like when they're finished, I am attaching this picture:

So, what I want is something so that I can specify "the gradient starts with colour X at angle A, and ends with colour Y at angle B". Does TikZ picture have such a function, or is it necessary to define something on one's own?
Look forward to your responses!
The only thing I've been able to come up with would be to use the method described in this answer to create a circular shape as a background, then to "hide" most of it with white with a cut-out of my shape remaining, but the problem with this approach is not only that it's kind of inelegant, it also will not work if I need to have several shapes next to one another.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72813749/tikz-fill-a-circle-with-shading-color-by-angle
EDIT: It being requested that I add some code snippet, I have put together this one, which produces the figure I have in mind, albeit without the desired gradient:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick, arrows=<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
\draw[thick, arrows=<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
\draw[fill=red, draw=none] (2.5,0) arc (0:225:2.5) -- (225:2.2) -- (243:3) -- (225:3.8)--(225:3.5) arc (225:0:3.5) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=blue, draw=none] (290:2.5) arc (290:335:2.5) -- (335:2.2) -- (353:3) -- (335:3.8) -- (335:3.5) arc (335:290:3.5) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

The image produced looks as follows:


To increase the chance of getting a useful answer it would be useful if you show some code, possibly together with a screenshot of what you achieved so far. This could be, e.g., a complete example which is missing the gradient.

Please always include a small code snippet that can be compiled.

@BanDoP Absolutely! I'll be right at it!

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/78347764/2777074

My apologies, including the link in the question!

Please can you make your snippet copy-paste-compile ready?

The only way to do this in PGF, as far as I understand it, would be to use a functional shading. That is, you'd define a shading which took coordinates as inputs and spat out suitable colour values for whichever colour model you're using. However, especially if you need to do lots of these, I don't think you want to do this. (1) Such functions are slow. (2) This cannot be mitigated by e.g. externalisation - the function is calculated by the renderer i.e. not at compile time. (3) Any given renderer may or may not produce the expected result. So, (4) you cannot know what your reader will see.

Maybe look at pgfplots?

Okay, so, I think I've found a solution. The code and the process of getting there is the ugliest mess you've ever seen, but in the end, it does seem to produce the images I want it to. I will write a longer response to it during the weekend.

Well, in honor of the little hair you have left, and so that you can see that it is only a matter of knowledge, and of finding a way to obtain workable answers because the first image you posted even requires the use of digital filters and that is beyond the scope At the user level, it would have to be the subject of a latex core programmer and programming a style generator for shading, but here's an example of how close you can get by iterating.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\definecolor{CusRed}{HTML}{FC003C}
\definecolor{CusBlue}{HTML}{00B3F6}
\definecolor{CusGreen}{HTML}{02A89D}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,arrows.meta,shadings}

\def\arcArrow[#1][#2][#3](#4)(#5)(#6)#7{%\arcArrow[Type][Color][Width](main_radius)(start_angle)(end angle){arrow tip-size_in degrees}
    \def\pathA{(#5:#4cm+#3)
        arc (#5:#6:#4cm+#3)
        -- (#6:#4)
        -- (#6:#4cm-#3) 
        arc (#6:#5:#4cm-#3)
        -- (#5:#4cm-#3*1.7)
        -- (#5+#7:#4cm)
        -- (#5:#4cm+#3*1.7)
        -- cycle;}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{pencildraw}}{
        \shade[pencildraw,line width=1pt,upper left=#2,
        upper right=white,
        lower left=#2,
        lower right=white, shading angle=#6]\pathA
    }{
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{PseudoStroke}}{
                \begin{scope}
                    \clip
                    \pathA
                    \pgfmathparse{int(#6+1)}
                    \xdef\Shift{\pgfmathresult}
                    \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \xn using {(\j-#6)/(#5-#6)}] in {#6,\Shift,...,#5}{
                        \fill[#2,opacity=\xn*\xn*0.4](\j:#4cm-#3) circle(#3*\xn*2.5+rand*rand*1.5mm);
                        \fill[#2,opacity=\xn*\xn*0.4](\j:#4cm+#3) circle(#3*\xn*2.5+rand*rand*1.5mm);
                        \fill[#2,opacity=\xn*\xn*0.4](\j:#4cm) circle(#3*\xn*2.5+rand*rand*1.5mm);
                    }
                \end{scope} 
            }
            {
                \shade[upper left=#2,upper right=white,lower left=#2,lower right=white, shading angle=#6]\pathA 
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >=Triangle,%Style for arrow tip
        pencildraw/.style={%fancy style for hand drawing lines
            decorate,
            decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=0.5pt}
        }
    ]
    
    % This is where the drawing just begins.
        \arcArrow[pencildraw][CusRed][7pt](2)(245)(0){10};
        \arcArrow[pencildraw][CusBlue][7pt](2)(340)(285){10};
        \arcArrow[Normal][CusRed][5pt](4)(90-10)(0){5};
        \arcArrow[Normal][CusRed][5pt](4)(180-10)(90){5};
        \arcArrow[Normal][CusRed][5pt](4)(270-10)(180){5};
        \arcArrow[Normal][CusRed][5pt](4)(360-10)(270){5};
        \arcArrow[PseudoStroke][CusRed][8pt](3)(245)(0){8};
        %a combination of two styles
        \arcArrow[pencildraw][CusGreen][8pt](3)(360)(275){8};
        \arcArrow[PseudoStroke][CusGreen][8pt](3)(360)(275){8};
        %Some aditional standard drawings.
        \draw[<->,pencildraw](180:5cm) -- (0:5cm);
        \draw[<->,pencildraw](-90:5cm) -- (90:5cm);
        \draw[pencildraw](0,0) circle (0.5cm);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}


Additional note:

In the Firefox PDF viewer, the shadings do not work, I don't know if it is because of the version I have, but everything is normal in Edge, and Acrobat.


Could you explain this a little bit? For the shading you're breaking the arc into bits and approximating them with straight lines rotated to match the tangent, is that right?

You bloody show-off, Sir! Making my own efforts appear absolutely bumbling and amateurish! I hate you, Sir! :P

Seriously, though, this is marvellous! I'm going to have to study every line of code you wrote in detail that I may benefit from it in the future! :D

@cfr , It is perhaps something more improvised, I made the iteration for each degree of difference between the final and initial angle, then a value \xn vary proportionally in that interval from 0 to 1, in this way for each iteration, 3 circles are drawn, one in the center and the others in the near and far tangents, then I only vary the opacity and size adding some noise using rand, you can see other near use results in palete shading, ring diagram

@StormyTeacup, Well, when I started I also hated the intelligible codes of many tikz masters, especially a groundhog that is now missing, who did not structure his code but was at a much higher level, they were good times, which I hope will return. You can see my gallery of answers to see that whole story.

@StormyTeacup Honestly, even my own code looks unintelligible to me most of the time.

In the end, using pgfplot turned out to be too much of a hazzle, at least for me, since they are very difficult to scale properly. After tearing my hair out for a day and a half, I just gave up and went with Inkscape. I generated the following background image:

Cut out the arrows I wanted from a white foreground, and presto:

This gives me the aesthetics that I want, and that are easy to manipulate.
